# Why would RSA_size crash?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography

I'm trying to use the OpenSSL crypto lib and it's crashing in a call that's a staple in every example I've seen.  Here's how it's set up:

```
BIO* bp = BIO_new_mem_buf(_publicKey, -1); // Create a new memory buffer BIO.
RSA* pubKey = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(bp, 0, 0, 0); // And read the RSA key from it.

unsigned char encryptedRandKey[RSA_size(pubKey)];
BIO_free(bp);
```

`_publicKey` is a null-terminated character string containing a PEM-formatted RSA key (with the `-----BEGIN XXX-----` and so forth).  It crashes with bad access in `RSA_size`.

It doesn't matter if I remove the `BIO_free`.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the return value of `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY()` to make sure it is non-null. Most likely the contents of `_publicKey` are not quite a correctly formatted key and as a consequence `pubKey` is NULL.

Comment: Duh.  Thanks for the pointer to the obvious!  The question now is what the problem is, because _publicKey is legit.  The only thing I can see is that maybe newlines got removed somehow.  The whole thing comes back from a database as XML, and the XML dump of that element to the console shows newlines for the -----BEGIN and so forth.  But a printf of _publicKey does not seem to have newlines.

Comment: @Oscar - Yes, OpenSSL needs the new lines in the PEM encoding. See [Can't set public/private key in OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29929327/608639) and the discussion around the answer. (And sorry to dig up an old thread).

Comment: No harm in that. Thanks JWW.

Answer (score 1):

Try `PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey` instead of `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY`.