# Can't set public/private key in OpenSSL

Tags: c++, c, encryption, openssl, rsa

I am trying to set the public and private key to an EVP_PKEY in C++ from a string. However, even after following several examples online, the PKEY always comes out as NULL. Here is the code to reproduce the problem (this is for private keys but the effect is the same for public keys):

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    EVP_PKEY *keypair;
    keypair = NULL;

    std::string privateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

    BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    if(BIO_write(bio, (unsigned char*)privateKey.c_str(), (size_t)privateKey.size()) != (int)privateKey.size())
    {
        BIO_free_all(bio);
        return 0;
    }

    PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bio, &keypair, NULL, NULL);

    BIO_free_all(bio);

    if(keypair == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "error";
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The private key you're passing is invalid; it's missing newlines. There needs to be one right after the `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` header, another one before the corresponding footer, and one after every 64 characters in the body, e.g.

```
std::string privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
    "MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAris+hDVFJ4l1PQnpToA+qE5ZpMT1maGngVFVy8JYdmhOALP/\n"
    "ETGiKU7MavTPFJmOy+vRlR6OdfsJgAq1tX7RGt0ua1S0bjq8BTWBi1Ja244uIbg+\n"
    /* ... */
    "5y/pFIsTIz7ngSJ1/dL8T/qbaDwB1zjCrmcfmxTcCEGfjiAUNVj1BvJ1eKO7UWTp\n"
    "CD0svGFc/FBULrgOlheVtpId4HN4j60LeSY7KZFjw7gtbWkKP6c=\n"
    "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
```

Comment: *"The private key you're passing is invalid; it's missing newlines."* - I'm surprised OpenSSL has not fixed that yet.... Its an arbitrary limit of 1000 characters in [RFC 821](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc821) and [RFC 1421](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1421). There's no reason to fail processing for lack of new lines, which are immediately removed.

Comment: Those RFCs aren't really relevant here, as this isn't email. [RFC 7468](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7468) actually sets a stricter requirement that every line must contain "exactly 64 characters except for the final line". Even if that weren't the case, though, the header/trailer lines need to be kept separate from the data anyway, so there'd still be at least two newlines missing.

Comment: for completeness,  RFC 7468 did not exist when those routines were cut-in :) The Base64 encoder came from the Email RFC, and the PEM encoding came from the PEM RFC. But its nice to see the behavior finally called out. And you are right about the encapsulated header boundaries - they do need new lines to delineate them.